# ASP.NET MVC5: Unobtrusive validation during the filling out of the form field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I want to make the validation element launched during the filling out of the form field.
If I create a simple MVC application that contains simple model:

```
public class SimpleModel
  {
    [RegularExpression("[A-Z][a-z]+")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("[A-Z][a-z]+")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

For this model I created the corresponding Controller and View(Razor using template Edit) for this model.
At this time, everything worked as it should. But only when clicking on the Save button(submitting the form), not during filling the field. That's why I wanted to implement action onkeyup of the validator in script section:

```
@section Scripts
{
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('form').validate(
      {
        onkeyup: function (element)
        {
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement(element, true);
        }
      });

  </script>
}
```

But it does not work and the original validation also does not work(now if i click the save, the form is submited as valid altrough fields are not filled or are filled in incorrectly).
And the original validation does not work if I use only 
     `$('form').validate();` 
or 
     `$('form').valid();`  
command.
And maybe it is interesting that 
    `$('form').valid();` 
returns true although form is not filled and thus is not valid.

Comment: Might be completely irrelevant, but the order of "script include" is important. Once I included the jquery.unobtrusive before jquery.1.0.js file, and the validation was not working due to that.

Comment: First is included the jquery, then the jquery.validation and then the jquery.validation.unobtrusive as declared in _Layout and BundleConfig. jquery.ui is not used.

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console? Hit F12 in your browser and see if there are any exceptions being thrown. Also, make sure you have not disabled default behaviour of unobtrusive. http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-3-configuring-unobtrusive.html

Comment: When I wanted to try the debugger, so IE announced "The script debugger failed to connect to the target process. 
A debugger is already attached." So I changed the onkeyup to:
onkeyup: function (element)
{
   console.log("onkeyup", element);
   //$.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement(element, false);
},
and in console I received the expected result(text "onkeyup" followed by input element tag FirstName or LastName) without any error.

Comment: now i open page in new instance of browser and i can debug code without message above. i went through the normal code for both fields. first one then the second. debugger, but it seems a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite easy. Just realize, that validation using a script it is possible after initialization of the unobtrusive. This initialization is performed by registering new jquery ready function - in  jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js at the bottom you find this code:

```
$(function () {
  $jQval.unobtrusive.parse(document);
});
```

Therefore, if it has to carry out additional initialization, so they must create own ready function and insert the necessary code.

For the purpose referred to in the question above, you can use this code:

```
@section Scripts 
{
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function ()
    {
      var validator = $('form').validate();
      validator.form();
    });

  </script>
}
```